# composer gives openssl error message php7 on linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, openssl

I have PHP 7 installed on arch, which comes directly with openssl packed in the PHP core. Composer does not seem to recognise it and gives me this error:

> [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
>   The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not
>   available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can
>   disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'dis
>   able-tls' option to true.

I don't want to disable TLS.
I tried to include this module in php.ini with various names like `openssl`, `php_openssl`, `openssl.so`, `php_openssl.so`, but none of that worked.

UPD0: I'm using Apache2.

UPD1: Distro: Arch.

UPD2: I have disabled the composer TLS protection but I am receiving another error message:

> [RuntimeException]
>   You must enable the openssl extension in your php.ini to load
>   information from https://asset-packagist.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just compiled PHP with flag --with-openssl